# Itext Ilist to pdf

Tags: c#, itext, ilist

I have an `IList` in c#, and I want to put it in PDF through IText.  Is there any way to do this? I have been searching for it for a while now.

What i tried to do was:

```
s = BLLstudent.selectStudentById(Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["s"]));
var data = BLLevk.selectEvkDetailsVanStudent(s.pk_studentID);

Document mySavedPDF = new Document();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Toon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\LilyNoone-LessLes-503729a\prints\" + s.studentNaam + "_" + s.studentVoornaam + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(mySavedPDF, fs);
mySavedPDF.Open();
mySavedPDF.Add(data);
mySavedPDF.CloseDocument();
```

But this said

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'System.IO.TextReader'   C:\Users\Toon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\evk-applicatie-181211\web\admin\a_overzicht_student.aspx.cs 95  77  C:...\evk-applicatie-181211\

Is there any way to insert the list directly?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to **directly** add a generic `IList` to the `Document` object directly. If you take a look at the [Document.Add method](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#add%28com.itextpdf.text.Element%29), the only valid parameter is an [Element object](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Element.html) - that's why the `Exception` is thrown. If you think about it, trying to add a generic IList to a PDF would be very difficult - at the minimum you would have to take into consideration both the IList elements `type`, and also how to format each member property (after you determine both type and members using `Reflection`) in the PDF.

So you have a couple of choices.

- Convert your IList to a simple XML representation, then send it to a [XMLWorker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) or [HTMLWorker](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html).
- Write your own wrapper or code to display your IList.

The second choice isn't so bad, and you have complete control of how to display your collection. Here's a simple example:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
IList<Student> students = Student.GetStudents();
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
    document, Response.OutputStream
  );
  document.Open();
  foreach (Student s in students) {
    document.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format(
      "[{0:D8}] - {1}, {2}. MAJOR: {3}",
      s.Id, s.NameLast, s.NameFirst, s.Major
    )));
    List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
    foreach (string c in s.Classes) {
      list.Add(new ListItem(c));
    }
    document.Add(list);
  }
}
```

With a simple class like this:

```
public class Student {
  public string NameLast, NameFirst, Major;
  public int Id;
  public string[] Classes;
  public static IList<Student> GetStudents() {
    string[] majors = {"Math", "Engineering", "CS"};
    List<Student> l = new List<Student>();
    for (int i = 0; i < majors.Length;) {
      l.Add(new Student() {
        Major = majors[i], 
        Id = ++i, NameLast = string.Format("LastNameStudent{0}", i),
        NameFirst = string.Format("FirstnameStudent{0}", i),
        Classes = new string[] {"Calc I", "Physics II", "Databases"}
      });
    }
    return l;
  }
}
```